# What is a new-tab-page-third-party in chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I recently opened my chrome browser after a crash and found the following displayed when I created a new tab

[image: chrome new-tab-page-third-party]

Looks suspicious, what does it mean exactly? I'm currently running Chrome 91.0.4472.77

[image: About Google Chrome]

Comment: I do not see that here.  I see New Tab and then chrome://newtab.   I think this is normal. Have you tried resetting Chrome?

Comment: Yah I've been used to seeing `newtab` too for a few years at least. I wonder if it has to do with google not being the default search provider. I'll experiment with that and see what's going on and search the chrome open source to see what's up there if I can find a bit.

Comment: It only happens when I do it on incognito though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks legitimate

https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/52c4e0d606a975dc5c1315422fb31db9e4406782/chrome/common/webui_url_constants.cc#L130-L132

Here's the commit from 3months back that introduced this UI for the New Tab Page (NTP)

> This CL creates a new default NTP for third-party search providers that
> do not have their own NTP define. It shows the most-visited tiles
> centered on the screen and can display a background is a chrome theme
> extension is installed.
> https://github.com/chromium/chromium/commit/dc334612cb78fa2233eb34c1355b6ee905f57cdc

Answer (score 2):

One advantage to the `new-tab-page-third-party` UI (intentional or un-) is, because it's search-engine driven it can act as a canary for search hijacking.

I recently worked on a system that previously had a bundled McAfee antivirus suite installed. Even after removal, it left a search hijacker behind that kept resetting Chrome's default search engine to their Yahoo!-based "Secure Search". The fact that the non-Google-branded new tab page kept coming up was  the red flag that clued me in to the search modifications.

Answer (score 1):

It also appears to occur if you have modified the browser's user-agent string (e.g., with a chrome extension like Chrome UA Spoofer). While the UA string is set to anything other than the Chrome default, new windows and tabs have the URL `chrome://new-tab-page-third-party/`.